# null pointer equivalence to int

Tags: c++, null, pointers

In "The C++ Programming Language", Bjarne writes that the null pointer is not the same as the integer zero, but instead 0 can be used as an pointer initializer for a null pointer. Does this mean that:

```
void * voidPointer = 0;
int zero = 0;
int castPointer = reinterpret_cast<int>(voidPointer);
assert(zero == castPointer) // this isn't necessarily  true
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that means that `castPointer` isn't necessarily zero, and the assert may fail. Because while the *null pointer constant* is zero, the *null pointer* of some type is not necessarily an address with all bits zero.

`reinterpret_cast` has no special provisions to yield zero when casting a null pointer to int. You can achieve that by using boolean operators, which will initialize the variable with either `0` or `1`:

```
int castPointer = (voidPointer != 0);
```

Comment: I wonder if anyone can point out a system where the implementation of a NULL pointer is not a bunch of zero bits.  Just curious if there's one out there.

Comment: There are. I can't name any though, but I've run into them before, in discussions like this. :)