# How to define NULL using #define

Tags: c++, c, null

I want to redefine NULL in my program such as

```
#define MYNULL ((void*)0)
```

But this definition is not working in the following statement:

```
char *ch = MYNULL;
```

> > Error : can not convert from void* to char *

What would be the best way to define NULL?

Comment: Which language? C or C++, they're very different languages

Comment: And why do you think you need to do this?

Comment: Can you change the name of the variable ch to something else (like `str`) as it's likely to confuse someone reading it quickly who might infer you're interested in NUL handling please. (But my real question is (as @Neil Butterworth asked), WHY?) (Or can you clarify what you're hoping to achieve? Are you trying to have a single manifest constant have double duty as both a pointer and a NUL character?

Comment: As it stands this is just a bad question, as you almost certainly shouldn't be doing this. Perhaps if you explain what your motivation is, the rationale might be clearer?

Comment: @Draemon: 6 upvotes say it's a great question :P (Only just added my -1... @cppdev: Don't forget to respond to all the followups this has generated!)

Comment: This is a worrying question - indicative of doing something bad.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#define MYNULL 0
#else
#define MYNULL ((void*)0)
#endif
```

will work in both of them.

Comment: @Ruben: I agree, however if you're writing a language agnostic library (i.e. you want the code to compile in both languages), you do need some way around this. That's said with the caveat that they are different languages, and a "language agnostic library" for C & C++ is a hack.

Comment: @Binary Worrier: If you're building a ground-up replacement of an entire Standard Library for the new compiler you've just carefully crafted in order to do a landgrab for market share in the quickly expanding market of C/C++ compilers, this is an excellent idea. If you're not in that position, I fail to see how this is going to improve on what's built-in *and* not have any bad side-effects such as not playing well with `nullptr` as noted in @Johannes's answer or any other future things it might interact with.

Comment: There's an onus on people like Yossarian who understand this, to push back on bad ideas as in addition to the obvious purpose of this site, which is for the FGITWs to solve the programming problems of the planet in record time all the time.

Comment: Didnt call it out explicitly but any `<stdlib.h>` that's supplied with a C/C++ compiler (and definitely a `<cstdlib>`) explicitly worries about all this crap so the coder (and more importantly the maintainer and the porter doesnt have to)

Comment: The question was 'how to define NULL using #define in C++ and C', as I understood it, it wasn't 'what to do with NULL if I wait till someone implements c++0x well', or 'are there any caveats using NULL'. Why don't you just assume that cppdev KNOWS exactly is he doing, and just wants answer to this question? This is what I hate about stackoverflow - Usually I've got reasons for using my solutions, and don't want tips how to do it some other way. (well, the question doesn't have premises to assume this). Use your magic orbs and other future-seeing accessories for something more interesting.

Comment: @Yossarian: Part of a good question (deserving of many upvotes) is to FizzBin and/or otherwise establish what you have and havent tried to do on your road to deciding to bother the LazyWeb with your Important Question). And dont worry about being the only person on the planet that gets irked by SO and it's many + and (not so many) - points (in every sense of the term) :P But while we're splitting hairs, you really do think that, measured against all the other answers on the site, this one is uniquely worthy of 96 rep? (And no, my answer isnt worth 60 - its a dup of a comment). Go Johannnes!

Comment: I refer you to the comments on the question, the downvotes on yours, the upvotes on the comments on the question for independent verification lest you get too tied up in me being a Bad Guy. And @Binary Worrier: I'm blaming you for keeping this answer looking credible!

Comment: I don't mind the - points, I just don't like your argumentation.

Comment: Give me a -1 with a comment and someone willing to stand over their opinion and/or justify it with an explanation of why they feel its correct over a -1 any day. For subtle things like this question, letting mob rule sort things out based on potentially flawed understanding using downvotes to cancel out upvotes based on incomplete understandings is just not good enough. I have to say this nonsense happens a lot more on the tags on this question compared to others I look at. As I say, we all hate SO :(

Comment: I answered the question, the askee obviously wanted this answer. Your answer is bunch of what-ifs, speculating about c++0x, and assuming that there is correct standard library for platform askee is developing for.

Comment: @Ruben Bartelink: As I've said, I agree. Justified blame taken to heart. Also, I might be available for that VERY deserved pint somewhere around the end of March. Hope all's well pal :)

Comment: @Binary Worrier: In my blinded rage, I missed the subtlety in your original comment and actually construed it as saying 'it's OK in some circumstances' - see there were no smileys, exclamation marks or anything :D I believe it's certainly being used by the other arguee as a crutch for the purposes of scaling further up a high horse. If you have to wait until end March for a pint it will indeed be very well deserved. Suggest me a day other than Friday and I'll pencil it into the diary...

Comment: Congrats on solving this intriguing puzzler for our gallant questioner who can now continue on the road to writing a language independent library that's going to be really easy to port and maintain over time thanks to your unique insight. Seriously though, the net number of votes or points, whether a questioner accepts an answer doesnt really count for much. I'd love to find out what exotic platform and issue we're actually dealing with here :D

Comment: I'm not sure, if you ever left the x86/x64 platform, but there are lot of embedded systems without ANY standard library (but with working C/C++ compilers), your ignorance isn't any valuable argument.

Comment: @Ruben Bartelink: Zing! Point for Yossarian! (sorry, couldn't help myself)

Comment: Lets not get into a platforms contest or calling eachother ignorant. Remember I've assumed all along (correctly I believe) that you know this is a Bad Thing To Do. I wouldnt be engaging the services of anyone asking the question in the form it was asked in working with a hypothetical bare bones compiler without a single header file anywhere #defining NULL. PS While you're irked, can you go downvote Johannes too as his answer obviously isnt as fantastic as this one! @Binary Worrier: This is like a late nineties flamefest, complete with people egging them on!

Comment: Sorry for the term ignorance, english isn't my primary language, I didn't mean to be rude, just found out it in dictionary [meant lack of knowledge]. The 'bare-boned compiler' isn't hypothetical, it is widely used, again, if you're developing just for big systems, you cannot have any clue of other uses of C. I can even realize that someone needs this in 'big system' project nowadays. (so no, I don't think that this is in general BTTD).

BTW: I'm not sure if you are the one to tell me who to up/downvote ;)

Comment: I am no authority on how to vote - just pointing out that putting random -1s on things without commenting isnt very cool unless you're going to have some consistency about it. As I said, not getting into platforms contest. And speculating about widespread fantastic compilers without any headers (maybe they dont even have a precompiler, hah :P) that the questioner is using is best left until  it is confirmed that we're actually in that territory. In the meantime, I'm calling this relatively Bad Advice (despite being technically correct) and 19 people are calling Johannes' answer Good Advice.

Comment: And while we're descending into pedantry, the questioner said **redefine** so we have evidence of this *not* being a unicorn scenario. I take it you're using the recent upvotes (and lack of ones for @Johannes' answer) as further justification for feeling so supremely justified :P

Comment: Seems like I have missed a good flamewar whilst beeing at school :-( I agree with @Ruben, there's nothing wrong with Yossarians answer per se. (As a side note it's not explicitly stated the OP needs C backwards compatibility besides the wrong tagging, so please don't belabor on providing "unnescessary" information). However, my answer shows the same solution plus it gives a general advice, so it's open to the community to decide which is the better answer. Downvoting to neglect upvotes is a common practice here on SO and there's no serious reason to discourage it.

Comment: @Ruben and Yossarian: Great point about the bare-boned scenarios though.

Answer (score 28):

```
#define MYNULL NULL
```

is the safest, I see no reason in doing so but if you really want to, go ahead.
Here's how C and C++ do it respectively:

```
#define NULL 0 //C++
#define NULL ((void*)0) //C
```

Generally speaking, defining 0 for NULL is a bad habit, you actually want it to be part of the language. C++0x adresses this.

This is what Bjarne Stroustrup has to [say on this](https://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#null):

> #### Should I use NULL or 0?
>
> In C++, the definition of NULL is 0, so there is only an aesthetic difference. I prefer to avoid macros, so I use 0. Another problem with NULL is that people sometimes mistakenly believe that it is different from 0 and/or not an integer. In pre-standard code, NULL was/is sometimes defined to something unsuitable and therefore had/has to be avoided. That's less common these days.
>
> If you have to name the null pointer, call it nullptr; that's what it's called in C++11. Then, "nullptr" will be a keyword.

Answer (score 10):

What exactly is the problem with getting your NULL from where you're supposed to?, i.e.,

```
#include <stddef.h>
```

or

```
 #include <cstddef>
```

as alluded to in @Johannes Rudolph's answer, any trickery you do is not likely be very future proof in the face of things like `nullptr` etc.

EDIT: while stdlib (and many others) are mandated to include a `NULL`, stddef is the most canonical header [and has been for decades].

PS In general, it's just a bad idea to get involved in this sort of trickery unless you have a really good reason. You didnt expand on the thinking that led you to feeling the need to do this. If you could add some detail on that, it's likely to lead to better answers. Other people answering the question should have pointed this out in their answers too, but I guess does FGITW as FGITW does best :D

EDIT 2: As pointed out by @Yossarian: The single justification for doing this is if there isnt a NULL defined in an appropriately language-agnostic form elsewhere in your system. Naked compilers with no headers and/or if you're writing your own custom standard library from scratch are examples of such a circumstance. (In such a bare-bones scenario, I'd go with @lilburne's answer (be sure to use `0` as much as possible))

Comment: @legends2k: Seems obvious to me (and @Neil Butterworth in the comments on the question but nobody +1'd that before me), but I guess people like solving puzzles that dont need to be solved.

Comment: @Ruben: Programmers, you see ;)

Comment: @legends2k: You mean 'Hackers' ! I guess people aren't on this site because they believe everything on the planet that need's saying has already been said :P

Comment: @Ruben: Well 'hackers', but not all of 'em, many of them are though :)

Comment: @-1er: Care to explain your downvote? if you have a reason why this is a wrong-headed answer, the world could benefit from the sharing of the reasoning. (I can offer a bunch of speculation and what-if's as to the identity of the mysterious voter if you wish!)

Comment: Ok. You solution assume working standard library. For developing ATMEL chips, there is C compiler, but NO standard library, no stddef.h. If you want to use NULL there, use maybe proprietal header, or define it yourself.

Comment: Ah, broadly applicable advise chopped down by a single insightful counterexample, wonderful. Nonetheless, will add proviso to cover this case which, while nit-picking in nature is possible.

Comment: @Ruben: Are there compilers with no standard library bundled? I.e. it only compiles code written in it's language with no support for standard library? I.e. you've to write functions for all your needs. I can't image this, the reason is, without malloc() or free() how will the programmer get memory (stack doesn't suffice always, I suppose)? Without having interrupt/signal (signal.h) how will the user handle signals from the OS?

Comment: @legends2k: There is no reason to disbelieve Yossarian's example. However the general advise holds - for something like NULL, have a look around you before reinventing it. There was a time when many Cs didnt have a NULL (esp when it was just defined as `0`). But there's always something that calls main() and gives you stuff like allocation like you suggest (though one cant assume dynamic memory capabilities are avail or necessary). Point is all this pedantry is very far from the questioner's origin now. Esp when even considering C and C++ together(and C++ is much less likely to have no stdlib)

Comment: This discussion descended into someone arguing black is white a long time ago though - don't go looking for nuggets of insightful information in this snowstorm! (If your just looking to have your opinion confirmed, I agree, if you're looking to supply ammo, I'm getting bored !)

Comment: Neat. Understood it clearly! Thanks for taking the time to explain. (well, I'm a new recruit, no ammo here ;)

Comment: @legends2k: Well then at least something good has come of the whole thing in the end - thanks for the kind words; Good luck!

Comment: I for example needed to define null in a task that has not standard (well any actually) libraries allowed.

Answer (score 2):

```
#define MYNULL 0
```

will work in C++

Comment: This will work only for C++. C needs NULL to be #defined as (void *)0.

Comment: @Paul: defining `NULL` as `0` works fine in C, just you lose a slight bit of type safety. However, using `0` properly for `NULL` in C won't create any errors. If you are going to rebut with the varargs sentinel value, it is recommend to case to `char*` even when using `NULL`

Comment: @Evan - you're right - I checked - thanks for correcting me !

Answer (score 2):

**Don't do this.**  <s>There is nothing that says that NULL has to be the value zero, it's implementation specific.</s>

It could be a value that represents the end of memory, some special place in memory, or even an object that represents no value exists.

Doing this is very dangerous, may break portability, and will most certainly screw with code-aware editors.  It isn't buying you anything, trust your library's definition.

EDIT: *Evan is correct!*  The code itself will say zero, under the hood the compiler can do what it wants with implementation specific details.  Thanks Evan!

Comment: this is a common mis-interpretation of the standard. The null pointer constant **is** 0. However the null pointer value (not exposed at a language level, so never your concern) may be machine specific.

C99 standard 6.3.2.3: "An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type void *, is called a null pointer constant.55) If a null pointer constant is converted to a pointer type, the resulting pointer, called a null pointer, is guaranteed to compare unequal to a pointer to any object or function." Which basically says "0 used in a pointer context is NULL."

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642763/null-pointer-equivalence-to-int/1642776#1642776 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423823/whats-your-favorite-programmer-ignorance-pet-peeve/1331729#1331729 and http://c-faq.com/null/machnon0.html

Comment: @Walt: no problem, I'll remove my -1 now :-).

Answer (score 1):

I think that anyone that doesn't know that setting a pointer in C/C++ to 0 is the same as setting it to NULL, nullptr, or any other equivalent shouldn't be messing with code. The difference in readability between

```
char* ch = NULL
```

and

```
char* ch = 0;
```

is minimal. When it comes to expressions the forms

```
if (NULL == ch) {
}
if (0 == ch) {
}
if (nullptr == ch) {
}
```

are no more readable than

```
if (!ch) {
}
```

Comment: @lilburne: Bringing nullptr into your example muddies things rather than clarifying them. nullptr has a purpose and isnt always 100% interchangeable with NULL. But I agree with the general point that for most usages one should consider preferring `0` and implicit cooercion to int to `NULL`. (But it's not getting a +1 from me while it's conflating these issues :D)

Answer (score 0):

In contrast to what some people state here, 0 is a perfectly valid definition for NULL in C. Thus you have to be careful when you give NULL as an argument to a variadic function, because it may be mistaken as the integer value 0, ending in non-portability.

http://c-faq.com/null/null2.html

BTW, the comp.lang.c FAQ is a highly recommended read for every C programmer. See for example here:

http://c-faq.com/null/null1.html

containing such gems of nearly-forgotten wisdom like "As mentioned above, there is a null pointer for each pointer type, and the internal values of null pointers for different types may be different." Which means that calloc or memset are NOT a portable initialization for pointers.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define NULL 0 //for C
```

is the perfect definition in C

e.g.

```
char *ch = NULL ;
*ch++ ;// will cause error
```

it causes error since ch pointing to nothing while executing increment statement 
is known by compiler by seeing the value of pointer in LOOK-UP table to be 0

if u try to update this pointer then u are actually changing the contents of 
CODE region which start at 0 physical address.
FOR that reason the first entry of page table prior to code region starts
is kept empty

What exactly is the problem with getting your NULL from where you're supposed to?, i.e.,

```
#include <stddef.h>
```

or

```
#include <cstddef>
```

as alluded to in @Johannes Rudolph's answer, any trickery you do is not likely be very future proof in the face of things like nullptr etc.

EDIT: while stdlib (and many others) are mandated to include a NULL, stddef is the most canonical header [and has been for decades].

PS In general, it's just a bad idea to get involved in this sort of trickery unless you have a really good reason. You didnt expand on the thinking that led you to feeling the need to do this. If you could add some detail on that, it's likely to lead to better answers. Other people answering the question should have pointed this out in their answers too, but I guess does FGITW as FGITW does best :D

EDIT 2: As pointed out by @Yossarian: The single justification for doing this is if there isnt a NULL defined in an appropriately language-agnostic form elsewhere in your system. Naked compilers with no headers and/or if you're writing your own custom standard library from scratch are examples of such a circumstance. (In such a bare-bones scenario, I'd go with @lilburne's answer (be sure to use 0 as much as possible))